# Velocities Turtlebot cmd_vel

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have a doubt concerning the velocities, especially the angular one. If I want to make Turtlebot spin 90 degrees for a second, for example, what angular vel. should I set? Would it change something if I also set the linear one?

I have this code:

ros::Rate loop_rate(1);   //Frecuencia de realización del bucle (10 Hz)

```
    while (ros::ok())   //Bucle mientras no se reciba "Ctrl+C"
    {
          vel.linear.x = 0;   //velocidad de avance
          vel.angular.z = 1.57;   //velocidad de giro

          vel_pub_.publish(vel);

          loop_rate.sleep();
    }
```

I guess that with this code, each message arrives each second. How should I modify this code to make the robot spin 90 degrees in one second?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60029/velocities-turtlebot-cmd_vel/) by [Bernardo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4106/bernardo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2013-04-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-04-05**:
Yes, this would send 1 msg/second. That is usually insufficient for controlling a robot as there are (hopefully) safety timeouts in place that stop any movement without data after something like 100ms. Send the message more frequently and stop after 1 second or do it properly with a controller as @joq suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To expand on the answer from @dornhege:

- simple, approximate controller:
- first publish to cmd_vel with angular.z = pi/2
- after one second, send another message with angular.z = 0.0
- better controller:
- at 10 or 20 Hz compute the angle in radians between your desired and current headings
- apply [PID feedback control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller) to that error signal

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3